# ¿Cómo exportar los resultados de un test estadístico en R?

Tags: r

Estoy corriendo una serie de tests y sería más cómodo exportarlos a un archivo de texto. He aquí un ejemplo:

```
x <- matrix(c(12, 5, 7, 7), ncol = 2)
write.table(chisq.test(table(x)), "x_CHI.txt")
```

y aparece el siguiente error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : cannot coerce class ""htest"" to a data.frame
```

Cualquier ayuda se agradece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza la función `capture.output()` para poder salvar los resultados en un archivo de texto. Utilizando tu mismo ejemplo:

```
x <- matrix(c(12, 5, 7, 7), ncol = 2)

resultados <- chisq.test(table(x))

capture.output(resultados, file = "prueba.txt")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es exactamente lo que estaba buscando.

Answer (score 1):

Una buena alternativa es utilizar el paquete **broom**, el cual transforma muchos de los objetos de R, como lo son los `chisq.test`, `lm`, `glm`, `ttest`, etc a un **data frame** (formato *tidy*).

```
x <- matrix(c(12, 5, 7, 7), ncol = 2)

test <- chisq.test(table(x))
#> Warning in chisq.test(table(x)): Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect

# Como output print
test
#> 
#>  Chi-squared test for given probabilities
#> 
#> data:  table(x)
#> X-squared = 0.5, df = 2, p-value = 0.7788

library(broom)

testt <- tidy(test)

# En data frame
testt
#>   statistic   p.value parameter                                   method
#> 1       0.5 0.7788008         2 Chi-squared test for given probabilities

write.table(testt, "x_CHI.txt")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. No conocía broom!